# How to Post and Update data in double nested serializer in django rest framework

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-3.0

I want to create a Quiz Rest API where I can post double nested serialzer data and update it also

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    questions_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
        verbose_name = 'quiz'
        verbose_name_plural ='Quizzes'


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    @property
    def questions(self):
        return self.question_set.all()




class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.label

    @property
    def answers(self):
        return self.answer_set.all()    


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

**views.py**

```
class QuizAPIView(generics.ListAPIView, mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    permission_classes = []
    serializer_class = QuizSerializer
    queryset = Quiz.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from question.models import Question, Quiz, Answer


class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['id', 'text', 'is_correct']


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answers = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.DictField(), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = [
            'id',
            'label',
            'order',
            'answers'
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        answers = validated_data.pop('answers', [])
        question = super().create(validated_data)
        for answer in answers:
            answer['question'] = question.id
            serializer = AnswerSerializer(data=answer)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
        return question

class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.DictField(), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'questions_count', 'questions']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        questions = validated_data.pop('questions', [])
        quiz = super().create(validated_data)
        for question in questions:
            question['quiz'] = quiz.id
            serializer = QuestionSerializer(data=question)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
        return quiz
```

I want to post request data like:

```
{
        "name": "GK5",
        "questions_count": 10,
        "questions": [
            {

                "label": "World Tourism Day is celebrated on-5",
                "order": 1,
                "answers": [
                    {

                        "text": "September 5",
                        "is_correct": false
                    },
                    {

                        "text": "September 51",
                        "is_correct": false
                    },
                    {

                        "text": "September 52",
                        "is_correct": true
                    },
                    {

                        "text": "September 53",
                        "is_correct": false
                    }
                ]
            }
]
}
```

But It give me an error when I call get request

**Error: for key, val in value.items()
AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute 'items'**

How can I fixed it ?